# How to generate access token for user in AZURE AD B2C using AzureADGraph or Microsoft Graph?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there a way to generate access token of a user using AZURE AD GRAPH client or MICROSOFT Graph client?
I have username and password ,client id, policy name. Using all these parameters. I want to generate the token.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that just with access token to initialize graph client. If yes. You could use the follow code to initialize Microsoft graph client.  `var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    requestMessage =>
                    {
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }));`

Comment: I mean to generate a accesstoken(bearer token) using the graph client, If I pass the username and password.

Comment: I have edited the question @TomSun . Please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could do that but it is not recommanded that to use the username and password to do that.

> In general Microsoft does not advise customers to use it as it's less secure than the other flows, and it is not compatible with conditional access (if the resource requires conditional access, the call to AcquireTokenSilent will just fail, given that this is not an interactive flow, the STS does not have an opportunity to present a dialog to the user to tell him/her that s/he needs to do multiple factor authentication).

Demo code.

```
var graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";
var clientId = "afa0b3fxxxxx";
var userName= "xxxxx";
var password = "xxx";
var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, clientId, new UserPasswordCredential(userName, password));
var accessToken = result.AccessToken
```

For more information, please refer to this [document](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-with-username-and-password).

**Update:**

**Get Refresh token.**

url:

```
post https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token
```

Header:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

body

```
resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net&client_id=xxxxx&grant_type=password&username=tom%40xxxx.onmicrosoft.com&password=xxxxx&scope=openid
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

Comment: I see this error

 The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'.

Comment: Do we have a sample code showing us all the steps to be done?

Comment: Could you please have a look @TomSun?

Comment: You need to use an azure AD native application

Comment: The token is generated. But this doesn't give me the refresh token.

Comment: Is there a way to get the refresh token along with it ? @Tomsun

Comment: This approach is not giving me the refresh token but just the id token

Comment: As you mentioned that there is no refresh token returned with SDK. If we want to get the refresh token, we could call the rest api directly. I will update the answer.